# Start: Applet Not Initialized Checkers Game

Tags: java, applet

So I'm working on an applet that plays the game of Checkers, and at this stage I'm just trying to set up the board. My code compiles, but when I open AppletViewer, I get a message saying "Start: Applet not initialized." Any idea as to why?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CheckerGame extends Applet implements MouseListener {
int player = 1;
Checker [] [] board = new Checker [8][8];
int mouseX = -200;
int mouseY = -200;
int col;
int row;

Image whiteChecker;
Image redChecker;
Image boardBG;
Image whiteKing;
Image redKing;
public void init()
{
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    boardBG=this.getImage(this.getCodeBase(),"checkerboard.jpg");
    whiteChecker = this.getImage(this.getCodeBase(),"whiteChecker.png");
    redChecker = this.getImage(this.getCodeBase(),"redChecker.png");
    whiteKing = this.getImage(this.getCodeBase(),"whiteKing.png");
    redKing = this.getImage(this.getCodeBase(),"redKing.png");
    for(int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++)
        {
            if(r < 3 && r%2 == 0 && c%2 == 1)
            {
                board[r][c].setPlayer(2);
                board[r][c].setKing(false);
            }
            else if (r == 1 && c%2 == 0)
            {
                board[r][c].setPlayer(2);
                board[r][c].setKing(false);
            }
            else if (r > 4 && r%2 == 1 && c%2 == 0)
            {
                board[r][c].setPlayer(1);
                board[r][c].setKing(false);
            }
            else if (r == 6 && c%2 == 1)
            {
                board[r][c].setPlayer(1);
                board[r][c].setKing(false);
            }
            else
            {                
                board[r][c].setPlayer(0);
                board[r][c].setKing(false);
            }
        }
    }
    this.setLayout(null);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX=e.getX();
    mouseY=e.getY();
    col = (mouseX-100)/100;
    row = (mouseY-100)/100;
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(boardBG,100,100,800,800,this);
    for(int r = 0; r < 7; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
        {
            if(board[r][c].getPlayer() == 2 && board[r][c].getKing() == false)
            {
                g.drawImage(whiteChecker,100+100*c,100+100*r,40,40,this);
            }
            else if(board[r][c].getPlayer() == 2 && board[r][c].getKing() == true)
            {
                g.drawImage(whiteKing,100+100*c,100+100*r,40,40,this);
            }
            if(board[r][c].getPlayer() == 1 && board[r][c].getKing() == false)
            {
                g.drawImage(redChecker,100+100*c,100+100*r,40,40,this);
            }
            else if(board[r][c].getPlayer() == 1 && board[r][c].getKing() == true)
            {
                g.drawImage(redKing,100+100*c,100+100*r,40,40,this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should open the Java Console and post any exception stack trace here. The error msg basically says that something is wrong with your `init()` method.

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 2):

Vollmilchbb is correct. Error in you `init()` method.

You have made a basic Java error. 
Though You have made a `Checker` array but haven't instantiated those elements.
Though you haven't show us your output logs (Console logs) here, you will find a `NullPointerException` in those logs.

It is just a part of your code but placing the code below inside those if blocks in `init()` method will do the job.

`board[r][c] = new Checker()`

**Rule:**
*Object arrays in Java (Except final class object arrays like String arrays) just make place holders(Pointers so to speak) for objects of type the array is declaring. You have to set an object or instantiate a new one before you access them.*

Comment: Yeah I literally realized JUST after I posted this. Woof